# Can phased-array (ULA) gain tapering effects be modelled using digital windows?

Tags: antenna, dsp, antenna-array

I am attempting to model the general behaviour of various tapering techniques. It seems applying gain tapering to a ULA has very similar effects to that of applying a digital window to a signal. In fact, some common tapering algorithms also exist in the DSP world (i.e., Taylor taper/window).

I am more familiar with signal processing techniques, so I am wondering if, for example, it would be fine to assume the behaviour from a Taylor window would be the same as applying a Taylor taper to a ULA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that is a valid analysis technique. Remember that a phased array antenna is essentially spacially sampling the incoming RF waveform, which is similar to time domain sampling a signal.  So the same, or at least  lot of the same analysis tools can be used in both domains.

FYI, the Matlab code I use for analyzing antenna patterns uses an FFT.